# Ending a sentence in the past tense with 'soon'

Tags: grammar, adverbs, syntactic-analysis, adverb-position, adjuncts

I was marking some exams for my Japanese high school students, and one of the test problems is:

```
Arrange the following words into a sentence:

walk / started / they / soon / to
```

Without fail, all ~300 students wrote:

```
They started to walk soon
```

...which definitely sounds wrong to me. I believe the correct response is:

```
They soon started to walk
```

However, for the life of me, I can't figure out why the position of **soon** makes such a big difference in this example. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I am not a Native Japanese speaker, but I can speak Japanese fluently. Japanese think English's word order (generally) is different from that of Japanese. For example, "I you love" is the Japanese order. Therefore, they think "soon" should be placed differently even though it is just an adverb. For this kind of adverb, the order should be same for both English and Japaness right after the subject and before the verb. I think it is somethig you need to emphasize to your students.

Comment: Could you add the tags [*adverb-position*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverb-position), and [adverbs](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Badverbs%5D+soon), please? I think the *past-tense* tag isn't really pertinent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that *walk* may take an **adverb**:

> They started to walk **quickly**.

So it attracts the modifier *soon*, which properly goes with *started*.  As you figured out, the way to get *soon* to modify the start and not the walk is to move the adverb closer to the verb it should modify and away from the verb it shouldn't.

Comment: So why are either okay in the future tense then?

`They will soon start to walk.`

or:

`They will start to walk soon.`

Comment: At that point, I would read 'start to walk' as in a child learning to do it. "His child was crawling enthusiastically at that age, and would soon start to walk."

Comment: @ThomasThrelfo An excellent question.  I do not know the answer.  Why does the future tense free the adverb to wander?  Perhaps the auxiliary *will* attracts the *soon* by making it slightly redundant.  You might ask the question on linguistics.stackexchange.com.